# Stripe figaro gem main:Object (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, figaro-ruby

I created a form for a rails 5 project for users to save there c/c on stripe for future pmts. I had it working successfully (successful code without implementing figaro below) prior to hiding keys using figaro. Now the server will  not start error below. Iv only used figaro on a couple occasions so I am having troubles implementing on this particular form. I feel i'm so close have I missed a step? Thanks for assessing.

Error from console:

config/initializers/stripe.rb:2:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method`“STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY”' for main:Object (NameError)

Successful code portion prior to figaro:

```
var stripe = Stripe('<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>');
```

code implementing figaro:

Payment.html.erb (portion that changed from successful code above )

```
<script>
  $(function() {

      var stripe = Stripe('<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:ENV[“STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY”]] %>');
      var elements = stripe.elements();
```

Stripe.rb folder

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => ENV[“STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY”],
  :secret_key      => ENV[“STRIPE_SECRET_KEY”]
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

Application.yml(secrets changed)

```
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY: "sk_test_UW12345678910t"
STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY: "pk_test_Fv1234567890p"
```

Comment: If you copied/pasted this directly from your app, you might want to double check that the quotes you're using in `ENV[...]` are regular double quotes (`["..."]`), because in the code above, they look like Smart Quotes (`[“...”]`).

Comment: I changed all quoted references and some how I used smart quotes (where ever I got those .. copied from reference mtrl I guess) it works like a charm... thanks so much!

Comment: well my server started great!! however I cant enter anything in the c/c field?? now what?